# How to check if Dotnet transaction is rolled back?

Tags: c#, commit, rollback, sqltransaction

How Can I check if a dotnet transaction is closed or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)){

    try{
        //Do something;

        scope.Complete();  //denotes the transaction completed successful.
    }
    catch(TransactionAbortedException ex)
    {

        //scope.Complete(); is never called, the transaction rolls back automatically.
    }
    catch(ApplicationException ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your title asks one thing and your question asks another. so, I am going with your title.

If you want to know if the transaction is rolled back or set to rollback only, you can check

```
transaction.WasRolledBack // true if transaction is rolled back
```

Here, `transaction` is an instance of ITransaction

**Edit (based on your comment)**:

```
var isRolledBack = false;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
{
  using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
  {
    try
    {
      // do your stuff here with transaction
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      transaction.Rollback();
      isRolledBack = true;
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can check the `isRolledBack` flag to see if the transaction is rolled back

Comment: I am sorry..for that mistake - I mean diff in heading and subject.     I am using SqlTransaction in C#. I am not sure...about ITransaction

Comment: @Anish: Updated the answer for sql transaction

Comment: Transaction.Rollback() can also throw exceptions. You should catch those too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL server, you can use `DBCC OPENTRAN`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182792.aspx

Comment: It's pretty clear from the question that it is not for SQL Server.